# Sending tab key event?

Tags: android, calabash

Is it possible to send a tab key press with calabash? I'm having difficulty selecting elements in a browser view on Android.

I've tried the following things:

```
enter_text("WebView css:'#Email'", "email@email.com")
enter_text("android.widget.EditText id:'#Email'", "email@email.com")
```

But they don't seem to be seen by calabash to select. I'm now wondering if I send certain number of tab presses, I should also end up in the field that I want. How do I send a tab key press though?

Additionally, is it possible to send text to an element that has the active focus, without specifying an id of the element?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is it possible to send a tab key press with calabash?"

Yes, it is.

> press_user_action_button('next')

If you are using Cordova, you should change the Webview to cordovaWebView or SystemWebView.

> enter_text("SystemWebView css:'#Email'", "email@email.com")

"Additionally, is it possible to send text to an element that has the active focus, without specifying an id of the element?"

Yes, it is.

> keyboard_enter_text("text")